# Install-Module -Name AzureAD -Scope CurrentUser -Force

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I am trying to install the AzureAD Module with Powershell on an Agent Windows 2019 Maschine in Azure DevOps. The scope is to query Get-AzureADGroupMember and see the members of that Azure AD Group. After running the DevOps Task seems that maschine is remaining in the state below, throwing
no status. Am I missing something?

```
Install-Module -Name AzureAD -Scope CurrentUser -Force
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
Connect-AzureAD
Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxx"
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command [Connect-AzureAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/connect-azuread?view=azureadps-2.0) need to add Credential to connect the AzureAD. By default, the Service Principal ARM Connection couldn't pass the required Credential to this command.

To use the Service Principal ARM Connection to connect Azure Ad, you need to add additional  task and script to achieve it.

Here is an example:

```
steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Azure CLI '
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: kevin0322
    scriptType: ps
    addSpnToEnvironment: true
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
     echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_CLIENT_ID]$env:servicePrincipalId"
         
     echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_CLIENT_SECRET]$env:servicePrincipalKey"
         
     echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_TENANT_ID]$env:tenantId"
     
    

- powershell: |
   az login --service-principal --username $(ARM_CLIENT_ID) --password $(ARM_CLIENT_SECRET)  --tenant $(ARM_TENANT_ID)
   
   $aadToken = az account get-access-token --resource-type aad-graph | ConvertFrom-Json
   
   Install-Module -Name AzureAD -Scope CurrentUser -Force
   
   Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
   
   Connect-AzureAD   -AccountId $(ARM_CLIENT_ID) -TenantId $(ARM_TENANT_ID) -AadAccessToken $aadToken.accessToken
   
   Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "xxx" 
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
```

You could use Service Principal ARM Connection in Azure CLI task, then you could get the  variables related Service Principal(enable **addSpnToEnvironment: true** ).

In Powershell task, you could use the variables from Azure CLI task to run azure cli command to get the aadtoken for Credential.

Finally, the  Connect-AzureAD command could be execute successfully without manually input the username and password.

Comment: do you see any constraints in running this on a Ubuntu Agent in DevOps?

Answer (score 1):

I checked the script.

The `Connect-AzureAD` prompts a UI for login

[image]

This could be the reason, why there is no progress.

You could pass along the credentials - this will prevent the login prompt.

```
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential
```

Comment: I am running this in a DevOps pipeline which is using a Service Principal ARM Connection to Azure. Is this not connecting via this Service Principal and take that credentials?